# How to fix Hibernate duplicating boolean fields in Java

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jaxb, jax-rs

I created a JPA Entity for a DB table. There is a boolean field "isPreferred". If I get entries of the table I have duplicate fields in the answer.
One with "preferred"=true and one with "isPreferred"=true.
I expect only the isPreferred field. How can I solve this problem?

I've already tried using Boolean wrapper class.
Also tried using setter like isPreferred and isIsPreferred/setPreferred and setIsPreferred.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@Entity
public class Address {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  private String street;
  private String houseNr;
  private String zip;
  private String city;
  private String country;
  @XmlElement(name = "isPreferred")
  private boolean preferred;

  ...getters/setters...

  public boolean isPreferred() {
    return preferred;
  }

  public void setPreferred(boolean isPreferred) {
    this.preferred = isPreferred;
  }
}
```

I expect only one boolean field in my response. Only the "isPreferred" field,
but actual I get preferred and isPreferred:

```
"addresses": [
    {
        "zip": "12345",
        "country": "DEU",
        "city": "Köln",
        "street": "Hauptstr.",
        "isPreferred": true,
        "houseNr": "1",
        "type": "homeAddress",
        "preferred": true
    }
],
```

Comment: Is the duplicate field present in your database? It looks more like a JSON serialization issue than a persistence issue. Then the question becomes: what's your JSON serialization library? What JAX-RS implementation are you using?

Comment: Try adding the `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` annotation in front of your class. It seems to be defaulting to `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)` in your case when it's unspecified. Also I'm fairly certain Hibernate is not part of the problem here.

Comment: `@XmlElement(name = "isPreferred")                                                                   
 @Column(name = "preferred")                                                                             
private boolean isPreferred;`                                                                                  
  // setter and getters of isPreferred                                                                            // may be used as a workaround

Comment: Hi, very, very rarely (about < 0.001%) questions are related to jpa (or the specific hibernate implementation) AND JSF, AND jax-rs. A combination of two of these is already less than 1%, so please try to narrow down the problem. And most likely (since you are 'generating' XML/JSON, the framework for that is waaay more relevant. Please take all things like that into account when adding tags to a question.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have two options in my opinion:

- Annotate the class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`
- Put the annotation `@XmlElement(name = "isPreferred")` on the setter of the field

Currently, you are creating a second field with the getter.

Answer (score 0):

If I debug into my responsing method I see only one field like expected, but in the postman response I have 2 boolean fields:
[debugger view with Response.ok(getAddresses()).build()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tfBg.png)

Comment: Hi, you can (=should) add this as a comment to the question. Not as an answer... Cheers!